# Unicode literals that work in python 3 and 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-2.x, unicode-literals

So I have a python script that I'd prefer worked on python 3.2 and 2.7 just for convenience.

Is there a way to have unicode literals that work in both? E.g.

```
#coding: utf-8
whatever = 'שלום'
```

The above code would require a unicode string in python 2.x (`u''`) and in python 3.x that little `u` causes a syntax error.

Comment: @ubershmekel Which solution would you recommend? Yours or the accept answer's?

Comment: I'd recommend using `u''` since it is now supported in python 3.3

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Edit - Since Python 3.3, the `u''` literal works again, so the `u()` function isn't needed.**

The best option is to make a method that creates unicode objects from string objects in Python 2, but leaves the string objects alone in Python 3 (as they are already unicode).

```
import sys
if sys.version < '3':
    import codecs
    def u(x):
        return codecs.unicode_escape_decode(x)[0]
else:
    def u(x):
        return x
```

You would then use it like so:

```
>>> print(u('\u00dcnic\u00f6de'))
Ünicöde
>>> print(u('\xdcnic\N{Latin Small Letter O with diaeresis}de'))
Ünicöde
```

Comment: I'd accept your answer if you removed the second part because it doesn't work for unicode literals that contain actual unescaped unicode. edit - I'd be just as happy if you clarified that nuance in the answer.

Comment: You don't pass in unicode literals, you pass in string literals, that's the whole point of it. I tried to clarify this.

Comment: "u() function isn't needed.", well it's needed in order to support the people who is still using Python 3.2.

Comment: Is a 'unicode literal' not a type of 'string literal'?

Comment: In Python 3 they are the same thing, in Python 2 they are not.

Answer (score 0):

In 3.0, 3.1, and 3.2:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

**Source**: [ubershmekel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/177498/ubershmekel), in the question. See [revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6625782/4) for the original.