# Gentoo Dropbox CLI

Tags: python, linux, unicode, dropbox, gentoo

Trying to use the python script to manage my dropbox via the command line and when I try to run it I get the following

```
-> ~/bin/dropbox.py help     
  File "/home/jcostanzo/bin/dropbox.py", line 50
    INFO = u"Dropbox is the easiest way to share and store your files online. Want to learn more? Head to"
                                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is my python version

```
-> python --version
Python 3.2.3
```

What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this script doesn't work in your version of Python.

The u'unicode' syntax works in Python 2.x, and again in Python 3.3.

See also [Unicode literals that work in python 3 and 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6625782/2153784)
and [What’s New In Python 3.3](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html).

Comment: Just eselect python set 1 which set me back to python 2.7