# Python3 : unescaping non ascii characters

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x

(Python 3.3.2) I have to unescape some non ASCII escaped characters returned by a call to re.escape(). I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339630/unescaping-escaped-characters-in-a-string-using-python-3-2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625782/unicode-literals-that-work-in-python-3-and-2) methods that doesn't work. I'm working in a 100% UTF-8 environment.

```
# pure ASCII string : ok
mystring = "a\n" # expected unescaped string : "a\n"
cod = codecs.getencoder('unicode_escape')
print( cod(mystring) )

# non ASCII string : method #1
mystring = "€\n"
# equivalent to : mystring = codecs.unicode_escape_decode(mystring)
cod = codecs.getdecoder('unicode_escape')
print(cod(mystring))
# RESULT = ('â\x82¬\n', 5) INSTEAD OF ("€\n", 2)

# non ASCII string : method #2
mystring = "€\n"
mystring = bytes(mystring, 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
print(mystring)
# RESULT = â\202¬ INSTEAD OF "€\n"
```

Is this a bug ? Have I misunderstood something ?

Any help would be appreciated !

PS : I edited my post thanks to the  Michael Foukarakis' remark.

Comment: Where are you executing the file in terminal/cmd or?

Comment: `"€\\n"` is not a Unicode escaped string, so you can not decode it to anything meaningful. `"€\n"`, if it were Unicode escaped, would become `b'\\u20ac\\n'`. So yeah, you seem to have misunderstood encodings.

Comment: A good point : I edited my post. But my problem is the same with the (non unicode) € character.

Comment: badcOre > the output is stored in a file and is printed in a terminal (urxvt).

Answer (score 2):

I guess the actual string you need to process is `mystring = €\\n`?

```
mystring = "€\n"  # that's 2 char, "€" and new line
mystring = "€\\n" # that's 3 char, "€", "\" and "n"
```

I don't really understand what's going wrong within `encode()` and `decode()` of python3, but my friend solve this problem when we are writing some tools.

How we did is to **bypass** the `encoder("utf_8")` after the escape procedure is done.

```
>>> "€\\n".encode("utf_8")
b'\xe2\x82\xac\\n'
>>> "€\\n".encode("utf_8").decode("unicode_escape")
'â\x82¬\n'
>>> "€\\n".encode("utf_8").decode("unicode_escape").encode("utf_8")
b'\xc3\xa2\xc2\x82\xc2\xac\n'  # we don't want this
>>> bytes([ord(char) for char in "€\\n".encode("utf_8").decode("unicode_escape")])
b'\xe2\x82\xac\n'  # what we really need
>>> str(bytes([ord(char) for char in "€\\n".encode("utf_8").decode("unicode_escape")]), "utf_8")
'€\n'
```

We can see that: though the result of `decode("unicode_escape")` looks wired, the `bytes` object actually contain the correct bytes of your strings(with utf-8 encoding), in this case, `"\xe2\x82\xac\n"`

And we now do not print the `str` object directly, neither do we use `encode("utf_8")`, we use `ord()` to create the `bytes` object `b'\xe2\x82\xac\n'`.

And you can get the correct `str` from this `bytes` object, just put it into `str()`

---

BTW, the tool my friend and me want to make is a wrapper that allow user to input c-like string literal, and convert the escaped sequence automatically.

```
User input:\n\x61\x62\n\x20\x21  # 20 characters, which present 6 chars semantically
output:  # \n
ab       # \x61\x62\n
 !       # \x20\x21
```

That's a powerful tool for user to input some non-printable character in terminal.

Our final tools is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys 

for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(bytes([ord(char) for char in line[:-1].encode().decode('unicode_escape')]))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to misunderstand encodings. To be protected against common errors, we usually  encode a string when it leaves our application, and decode it when it comes in.

Firstly, let's look at the documentation for unicode_escape, which states:

> Produce[s] a string that is suitable as Unicode literal in Python source code.

Here is what you would get from the network or a file that claims its contents are Unicode escaped:

```
b'\\u20ac\\n'
```

Now, you have to decode this to use it in your app:

```
>>> s = b'\\u20ac\\n'.decode('unicode_escape')
>>> s
'€\n'
```

and if you wanted to write it back to, say, a Python source file:

```
with open('/tmp/foo', 'wb') as fh: # binary mode
    fh.write(b'print("' + s.encode('unicode_escape') + b'")')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My "encoded" string ("\€\n" by example) has a very Pythonic origin : it's the value returned by a call to re.escape(). As far as I known there's no inverse function such as re.unescape(). Hence my attempt to decode the "escaped" string. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: The answer to the question "which is the suitable encoding?" depends on how it is going to be used. So, what is your use case? Also, are you sure `re.escape` is necessary, i.e. are you using user input as a regex?

Comment: These strings are read from a UTF-8 encoded file and will be written as UTF-8 strings in another file. Luckily, I don't mix different encodings.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
printable = string.printable
printable = printable + '€'

def cod(c):
    return c.encode('unicode_escape').decode('ascii')

def unescape(s):
    return ''.join(c if ord(c)>=32 and c in printable else cod(c) for c in s)

mystring = "€\n"
print(unescape(mystring))
```

Unfortunately `string.printable` only includes ASCII characters. You can make a copy as I did here and extend it with any Unicode characters that you'd like, such as `€`.